# Laravel 4 - Cookies aren't saved on local server

Tags: cookies, laravel, laravel-4

Following the docs I have created a cookie to last "forever" (5 years) on my local virtual host (indgo.dev).

so this:

```
 $cookie = Cookie::forever('hash',$project['hash']);
  dd($cookie);
```

outputs:

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie)#436 (7) {
  ["name":protected]=>
  string(4) "hash"
  ["value":protected]=>
  string(360) "eyJpdiI6IlNJcUJZSElRTlwvQ0dJU3Z4dE44VFwvYjJ3U3lpckRZY2xsV3NlWTJ5VHJ1dz0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkFHeFJGOXhjSzZxTkhZWGpIMiszUWZ5eXBUT2xuMTZFalpXdVZ3VW1CYUh1SmxKZUNPMk1rSFhONFk4REVkMzBtWlluWVhWU21uVHJXMDllKytmYm5idk5IVTNcLzIrUEgyZ3dsVllVTERyeTROU1lKUHUwb1ZpRll2V1JmU0Z4bSIsIm1hYyI6Ijc1YzcyODlkOTU0MGQ3ZjEyMDJhNjk5ZWNhOWY2ZWNhMGRhNzU4NjZiOTAwNGUzMjY1MzI2YjhhNGZjMWVhMzgifQ=="
  ["domain":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["expire":protected]=>
  int(1523085636)
  ["path":protected]=>
  string(1) "/"
  ["secure":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["httpOnly":protected]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

However, when I try to get the cookie on ***a differernt request***:

```
$hash = Cookie::has('hash');
    dd($hash);
```

I get `false` (or `null` if I use the `get` method)

Using Chrome Dev tools I found that indeed the cookie doesn't show. The only ones listed are `laravel_payload` and `laravel_session`.

UPDATE: When I login a new `remember_me` cookie *is* created by the `Auth` class

Comment: Try using Cookie::get('hash'). Maybe L4 has slightly different impelemntation of Cookies, its still not documented on four.laravel.com.

Comment: actually it is: http://four.laravel.com/docs/requests#cookies. And as I said I already tried the `get` method as well

Comment: already answered by me here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777824/cant-set-cookies-in-laravel-4/)

Comment: I read your answer b4 I posted my question. I **am** trying to get the cookie on a different request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not sending the cookie in the response. Try

```
$cookie = Cookie::forever('hash',$project['hash']);
return Response::make()->withCookie($cookie);
```

on the first request, then try to get the cookie.

Comment: Thanks. It works. How would I go about sending a view as a Response along with the cookie?

Comment: You can send a view to a response with

    return Response::make(View::make('hello'));

and can attach a cookie to it with

    return Response::make(View::make('hello'))->withCookie($cookie);

Comment: I tried something similar to your example and I couldn't fetch the cookie in any request after it was set. The cookie was there but it was impossible to read it. Until I figure out that Laravel doesn't allow `.` (dot) in cookie name. Actually it stores the cookie, but doesn't get it later.

Comment: The dot is probably used to get a value from an array.  So if you set your cookie like ```Cookie::forever('hash', ['first' => 1]);``` you will be able to fetch it via ```Cookie::get('hash.first');```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the issue with the cookie. Just in case the Laravel 4 newbies, if you need to set the cookie you need to send the cookie to any response. in my case I was showing a splash screen and need to set & check that when the user comes to the site. The splash screen has something like the following:

```
if(Input::get('splash') || Cookie::get('splash')) {
    $cookie = Cookie::forever('splash', 'checked');
    return Redirect::route('home')->withCookie($cookie);
} else {
    //show the splash screen with the form which has the splash = 1 as a hidden input
}
```