# Setting Cookies in Laravel 4 only works in App::after()

Tags: php, cookies, laravel, laravel-4

I try to set a `Cookie` in Laravel 4 in a specific route.

Unfortunately, setting the `Cookie` does only work in the global `App::after()` filter.

First thing I tried was returning a response with a `Cookie`from my `Controller`.

This doesn't work:

```
return Response::make($view)->withCookie(Cookie::make('foo','bar'));
```

However, this does:

```
return Response::make()->withCookie(Cookie::make('foo','bar'));
```

But does not solve my problem.

Next I tried it with an `after` filter as follows.

```
Route::filter('cookie', function($route, $request, $response)
{
    $response->withCookie(Cookie::make('foo', 'bar'));
});
```

This does not work either.

Next, I tried it using `Cookie::queue()`, which I've found in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777824/cant-set-cookies-in-laravel-4) - with no luck.

The only place the Cookie is set properly is in `App::after()`.

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    $response->withCookie(Cookie::make('foo', 'bar'));
});
```

Besides I'm pretty sure that one of the other approaches should work, this solution doesn't give me the control I'm looking for.

I'm running Laravel v4.0.9.

Comment: How are you trying to access the cookie? Remember that cookies are not available until the **next** page load. That's just how cookies work, regardless of framework implementation.

Comment: I use the (Browser) Web Inspector to check if the cookie is set or not.

Comment: I think the problem is when you set a cookie 'before', the response object is not yet created. Then in your controller, you create a 'new' Response::return() etc - so any previous values are overwritten. That is why it is working on your 'after' filter, because you are adding it to the created object.

Comment: But then why  doesn't it work in the custom after filter? There I attach the cookie to the response. Furthermore, it can be found in the documentation (http://four.laravel.com/docs/responses): `return Response::make($content)->withCookie($cookie);` and the queue approach is explained here: http://laravel.com/docs/requests#cookies

Answer (score 1):

Try this tested, working code.
Specify expiration time (in minutes from now). Dont you use some cookie extension in your browser, which may protect/blacklist specified cookies from being modified...

```
Route::get('cookieset', function(){
    $cookie = Cookie::make('foo', 'bar', 60);
    return Redirect::to('cookieget')->withCookie($cookie);
});

Route::get('cookieget', function(){
    dd(Cookie::get('foo'));
});
```

Comment: This does work indeed. I implemented it the same way (using a redirect) at first. However, the redirect prevents the application from being loaded properly, when embedded in a Facebook page with a Fangate using IE9 (leads to a redirect loop).

Comment: IE needs some little more effort to make it work in IE. Try to set this header `App::after(function($request, $response)
{
   $response->headers->set('P3P','CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM"');
});`

Comment: The problem is not IE specific and I already set the P3P header - although mine looks like this `$response->header('P3P', 'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');`