# Trying to set cookie in ajax call, Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, cookies, laravel, setcookie

I am trying to set a cookie in an ajax call, but can't get it to work.
I have understood that I need to set it via setCookie on $response->headers.
The $cookie variable looks correct, but no cookie is set in the browser.

Code from my controller:

```
$cookie = Cookie::make('testcookie', array('testvalue' => 'test'), 1000);  
$response = Response::json(array('status' => 'ok'));  
$response->headers->setCookie($cookie);  
return $response;
```

Comment: any warnings in error_log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are calling this function after the page is initialized. So no cookie headers can be sent after the html tags started.

Refer to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777824/cant-set-cookies-in-laravel-4) will help you

Comment: I verified that no output has been done when I try to set the cookie.
The problem seems to be that I am trying to set the cookie in an ajax-call?

Comment: I hate my self right now :-)
You are so correct shan! By accident one of my classes had a blank space before the opening php-tag.

Removing that solved the whole thing :-)

It's strange that I didn't see any errors from laravel similar to the normal you get from setcookie when content has already been sent. Thanks a million!!!!

Comment: @user3505343 : no worries :)
we all do silly mistakes all the time. Glad your problem solved. Good luck with your project.

Comment: so, what is the answer? i still confused that my cookies not changed with json